# How to find a covariance matrix of minimal volume including all data points by Mahalanobis distance?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normal-distribution, covariance, mahalanobis-distance

Let $v_i$ be real vectors from $R^D$, for $i=0..N-1$.

How to find a real symmetric positive-definite matrix $\Sigma$ so that

- $v_i^T \Sigma^{-1}v_i \leq 1$ for any $v_i$ and
- $det\ \Sigma$ is minimal?

In human words: How to find a Gaussian ellipsoid having minimal volume so that Mahalanobis distance to any data point is limited by some constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a very standard so called MAXDET program, for which there are specialized solvers. More generally, it is a semidefinite program. Here is a full example in the MATLAB Toolbox YALMIP (disclaimer, developed by me). It requires a semidefinite programming solver, such as Mosek, SeDuMi, SDPT (which has specialized code for the determinant part)

```
v = randn(2,10);
P = sdpvar(2);
Model = [P>=0];
for i = 1:size(v,2)
    Model = [Model, v(:,i)'*P*v(:,i) <= 1];
end
optimize(Model,-logdet(P))
x = sdpvar(2,1);
clf
plot(x'*value(P)*x <= 1);
hold on;
plot(v(1,:),v(2,:),'*')
```

https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/maxdetprogramming/

Comment: Johan, thank you very much! So it's MAXDET optimization problem. Don't you know which computational complexity my task has, "Minimum volume ellipsoid containing given N points"? (Actually it's even simpler, my ellipsoid is centered at zero)

Comment: If you mean what the complexity of the MAXDET problem is, it is theoretically in the  O(N^7) range or something like that in a straightforward formulation (P will have O(D^2) variables, and you at-least have cubic complexity in every iteration, and the number of iterations is proportional to square-root, i.e. O((N^2)^0.5). That is an upper bound which probably says nothing about practical performance, which more likely is in the order of D^3 to D^4 I would guess, considering sparsity etc.

Answer (score 0):

An interpretation of this question could lead to fitting a guassian with $\mu = \mathbf{0}$ and $$\Sigma = \frac{1}{N}\sum_iv_iv_i^T$$However the requirement that $\max v_i^T \Sigma^{-1} v_i \le 1$would mean that you would need to multiply it by a scale factor $\eta$. This would depend on what the largest value is, but you should be able to find that easily enough (its just normalizing).

Comment: ck4e, thank you. So you propose to fit the ellipsoid by L2 norm and then just scale it by maximum Mahalanobis distance? Actually I thought to do the same, it's not equivalent to original problem, but it will be close to (and fast)...

Comment: Now I do it a bit differently: find first eigenvector as a direction to the most distant point, then subtract from all points their projection to the first eigenvector and find the second eigenvector as a direction to the most distant point (in a subspace perpendicular to the first eigenvector) and so on. It's also fast algorithm (I need real time), but it looks more like "find oriented parallelepiped with minimal volume".

Comment: Sounds interesting! I'm not sure what the end goal is, and I'm assuming there are additional properties you need: I think your problem statement as is would result in the determinant of your covariance matrix to tend towards zero if its not bounded. But yeah, your determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, so if you minimize those, you would be minimizing the determinant.